# Question on Kubernetes load balancer policy

Tags: kubernetes, load-balancing

I've deployed my service on Kubernetes cluster and set-up 3 replicas(deployment with object Deployment, service with object LoadBalancer). What I expect is all 3 replicas are serving to multiple(~200) concurrent requests, but after inspecting the log, only 2 of them are functioning. How does that happen? How should I make 3 of them all serve?

More context: I've already opened multiple streams, and have one stub in each gRPC stream. So I assume single TCP connection per stream is not the reason.

Comment: Which version of Kubernetes did you use and how did you set up the cluster? Did you use bare metal installation or some cloud providor? Could you attach your yaml files? Please paste also your logs.

Comment: Oh sorry for the latency. According to this article(https://kubernetes.io/blog/2018/11/07/grpc-load-balancing-on-kubernetes-without-tears/), one single TCP connection cannot be load balanced to different servers, even if they belong to different gRPC streams. So my method is allocate them in mulitple TCP connections.